# What is the effect of using a # in front of a UNIX command?

Tags: linux, unix

My guess from the working of it is that it suppresses the output of the command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suppresses the command entirely.

You use it commonly in batch files to either add a comment to your code (explaining to the reader what is going on) or stop a line from running - for example:

```
# Tell the user the results 
cat $HOME/.temp/results.txt

# This next line doesn't work
# cat $HOME/.temp/next.txt
```

The equivalent in DOS is to prefix the line with `REM`.

Answer (score 1):

On the command line it's just a comment. Nothing happens.

```
#mkdir temp  -> yields nothing.
```

In a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

or

```
#!/bin/perl
```

has a special meaning to indicate the interpreter.

Otherwise it's used to comment out the line.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, a [Wikipedia article](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) on shebang (the #! sequence).

Comment: I think you mean "interpreter", not "interrupter" :)

Answer (score 0):

It makes bash (assuming that's what you are using) and most other shells view that line as a comment, therefore, "running it" does nothing.